# iTunes Connect: Check how many users for specific version

Tags: app-store-connect

I was wondering if there was a way in iTunes Connect to view if/how many users are using a specific version.

The reason is I am on version 2 and want to do something that would cause version 1 to crash, so I want to check if people are still using version 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the steps:

1. Go to App Analytics
2. Select your application
3. Select "Metrics" tab
4. Add filter "App Version"
5. Choose any element from left panel